# Editing tasks in vue

Tags: vue.js, vuex

cannot edit list
I think the problem is in the update mutation.
Everything is fine with the label, probably a problem with input, it does not update the data.
I need to make the tasks can be edited on a double wedge.

cannot edit list
I think the problem is in the update mutation.
Everything is fine with the label, probably a problem with input, it does not update the data.
I need to make the tasks can be edited on a double wedge.

```
Vue.use(Vuex)

export default new Vuex.Store({
    state: {
        todos: localData().get()
    },

    mutations: {

        editTodo: (state, id) => {
            let todo = state.todos.find(todo => 
                (todo.id === id))
            todo.edit = true

            localData().set(state.todos)
        }, //mutations editTodo

        update: (state, id, newEvent) => {
            let todo = state.todos.find(todo => 
                (todo.id === id))

            todo.title = newEvent
            todo.edit = false

            localData().set(state.todos)
        },
    },
})

<template>
<li>
    <label 
        v-if="!edit"
        @dblclick="editTodo"
    >
        {{ title }}
    </label>
    <input
        v-else
        class="edit" 
        type="text"
        :value="newEvent" //it seems he is interrupting the title

        @keyup.enter="update"
    >
</li>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    name: 'todo',
    props: ['id', 'title', 'edit', 'completed'],

    data() {
        return {
            newEvent: '' //Am I doing the right thing to add newEvent?

        }
    },

    computed: {
        todos() {
            return this.$store.state.todos
        }
    },
    methods: {
        editTodo() {
            this.$store.commit('editTodo', this.id)
        },
        update() {
            this.$store.commit('update', this.id, this.newEvent) //update method

        },
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First, let's define what is wrong in your code. You're updating Vuex state object using `update` function but you're giving `:value="newEvent"` which is in your component, so Vuex doesn't see this. First, create state data and getters for newEvent

```
state:{
  //..
  newEvent: ""
}

getters:{
  newEvent: state => state.newEvent
}
```

Then use this state element in your component

```
// ..
import { mapGetters } from "vuex"    

// ..
computed:{
  ...mapGetters(["newEvent"])
}
```

You should use logic like that